# Given two lines in Cartesian form, find the vector equation of a line which passes through the intersection of two lines.

Tags: vector-spaces

Given two lines in Cartesian form, find the vector equation of a line which passes through the intersection of two lines (and is perpendicular to both). No points given just the two equations. What are the steps to solve this?

For example:
Line 1: $x+1=\frac{y}{3}=-z$, 
Line 2: $2x+1=2y+1=z-\frac{3}{2}$.

Comment: Answered you analytically down below. Make sure to ask me anything you didn't understand. Also, if this answer is the one that makes you solve your question, please make sure you vote up and mostly important approve the answer so that the thread goes down as answered.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$x+1 = 2x+1 \Leftrightarrow x = 0$

$\frac{y}{3} = 2y + 1 \Leftrightarrow y = 6y + 3 \Leftrightarrow y = - \frac{3}{5}  $

$ z - \frac{3}{2} = -z \Leftrightarrow 2z = \frac{3}{2} \Leftrightarrow z = \frac{3}{4} $

So the point $P$ of the intersection is : $P=(0,-\frac{3}{5},\frac{3}{4})$

The parallel vectors to the lines are : $n_1 = (1,3,-1) $ and $n_2 = (\frac{1}{2}, \frac{1}{2}, 1)$.

A vector perpendicular to these 2 is : $n_p = n_1 \otimes n_2 = (\frac{7}{2},-\frac{3}{2},-1)  $

$n_p =(\frac{7}{2},-\frac{3}{2},-1)  $  will be the parallel vector of your line and your line passes through $P=(0,-\frac{3}{5},\frac{3}{4})$.

So the equation of the line is : $\frac{2x-}{7} = -\frac{2y+ \frac{3}{5}}{3}=-z +\frac{3}{4}$